# How to create a global alert dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to make a "global" alert dialog for some of my activities. What i mean is that i created a class that extends `Activity` also created a function for the alert dialog that takes two parameters (message and title).

```
public class MyDialogAlert extends Activity {

public void createDialog(String title, String message)
{
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle(title)
    .setMessage(message)
    .setPositiveButton("yes", new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //(e.g) open another activity
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("no", new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //some stuff ..
        }
    })
    .show();
}
```

}

How can i call this function in different activities and change it`s negative and positive buttons to do other operations than those defined initially in the above class?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You could create a custom dialog class for this behaviour. An activity is a overkill. Pass parameters to the dialog constructor and construct dialog based on the params

Comment: You would have to take in at least one `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` as an argument to the method, and use those in place of the `new OnClickListener` anonymous inner classes. But, as @IllegalArgument mentioned, this is a bit overkill. Also, doing it this way basically negates the flexibility that the dialog builder provides.

Answer (score 7):

You can create sperate class that have static method for showing dialog on any activity

```
public class DialogCaller {

public static void showDialog(Context context,String title,String message, 
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener onClickListener) {

    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    dialog.setTitle(title);
    dialog.setMessage(message);
    dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok",onClickListener);
    dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",null);
    dialog.show();
}
}
```

And calling the method will be like this

```
   DialogCaller.showDialog(this,"title","message",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: how to dismiss it ?

Comment: I have been trying to show progress bar via alter dialog but i am having some issues can you please check my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63393532/8868582)?

Answer (score 0):

According to [FinalDark's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27033964/9039350) working answer and Faisal Qayyum question, i hope it helps someone on how to dismiss the dialog and adding negative button listener

In the calling method, add switch case:

```
DialogCaller.showDialog(this,"title","message",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           switch (option) {
             case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                  // Add your code if it positive button
                  break;

             case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                  // Add your code if it negative button
                  break;
          }
        }
    });
```

And if you want to add listener when the negative button clicked, just change `null` to the listener:

`dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",onClickListener);`